# If our eyes see at the speed of light, how do we know about the current states of stars and galaxies far away?

Tags: speed-of-light, stars, galaxies

As you guys know that we see at the speed of light, it means that we see the past of stars and galaxies. So say a star went supernova right now, how are we able to know current state of that star that is thousands of light years away or is it possible!!!

Comment: Who told we can see its current state? But astronomers can predict how the star's will turn out to be by looking at their past. That's how they make predictions.

Comment: The "current state of the universe" is not a well defined concept in relativistic physics. Will there be a sunrise tomorrow? Most likely. Will we see the same star tomorrow? Most likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We wouldn't be able to see it if a star went supernova right now because the light wouldn't have reached us yet. If a star 100 light years away from us went supernova 100 years ago we would see it now because the light would have had enough time to travel to us.

Answer (score 2):

While some galaxies are billions of light years away, there are hundreds of galaxies withing just a few dozen million light years away. Astronomically speaking, a few dozen million years is pretty brief. We can be fairly certain that the galaxy hasn't changed much in this time.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of light isn't an infinite value and light does not travel instantaneously. The speed of light is defined as 299,792,458 meters per second. This means that if a star that is 1 billion light years away went supernova right now, humans would not see the effect until 1 billion years from now.

Answer (score -1):

If a star 100 billion light years away goes super Nova it means it will be 100 billion years for us to see it.

Comment: Not true, because the universe is expanding as the light travels through it, so the light has to travel more than 100 billion light years to reach us.